# NetBeans create and instantiate programatically custom swing widgets

Tags: user-interface, swing, netbeans, components

I have a problem I know how I would solve easily developing under eclipse - but not so easily developing under net beans.

I want to create a custom swing widget - which I can instantiate by code as many as I need and attach them to my main panel.

I have developed the rest of the GUI using the GUIBuilder.

The problem is - im not entirely sure how to do this.

Say I got 20 results back from a web service,

I would wana loop round - and add 20 of these custom swing widgets - the custom swing widgets would look as follows :

```
:Picture: 
:Label: 
:Label:
```

Can anybody please help me, im not entirely sure how to do the custom widget either!

Thanks in advance for any support.

Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the question is probably too old to answer it but just for the Google effect:

1. Create a custom swig class (e.g. derive it from JPanel)
2. Drag the source class file listed in the tree diagram on the left and drop it on its supposed parent widget

Comment: +1 for answering because of the `Google effect`.  That's what brought me here!